# MySQL Workbench "->" Support

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

It looks like MySQL Workbench is now supporting JSON functionality, however I'm still seeing parser errors on MySQL 5.7.9 functionality, such as the "->" operator.

When I use the following query, I'm getting a syntax error over the "$.test" portion:

**Record**

`record: {"test": 123}`

**Query**

`SELECT test->"$.test" FROM table`

The query still executes successfully, however I'm curious as to why the syntax parser is incorrectly showing an error.

Comment: Which WB version do you use? 6.3.8 supports this syntax (also the "-->" operator).

Comment: I'm using version, 6.3.8 1228 CE.  See screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/8IfHD.

Comment: And what server version is it connected to? MySQL Workbench enables language features specifically for the server it works with (or for modeling the model server version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem is probably something else than what I posted in my comments. You are using double quotes, which represent strings only if the ANSI quotes are not enabled (then they wrap identifiers). Use single quotes instead.

Comment: So, this appears to be the issue.  Should I set the "Default SQL_MODE for syntax checker" to something else to get this feature to work with double quotes?

Comment: Nope. Instead disable ANSI_QUOTES in your connection settings (rather: don't enable). This setting affects all double quote delimited strings (and makes them identifiers). Alternatively use single quotes for your JSON expressions.